# ngxs store dispatch actions are not called in the specific order

Tags: angular, redux, ngxs

I am using NGXS for store management and dispatching the following actions to update the store using the following syntax.

```js
this.store.dispatch([
  new ChangeObjectActions.AddChange('modify', layoutName),
  new LayoutActions.SequenceChangeByDragDrop(
    layoutName,
    prevIndex,
    currentIndex
  ),
  new ChangeTransactionsInfoActions.UpdateChangeElementSequenceChange(
    this.changeElementSequenceSectionChangeService
      .getChangeElementSequenceChangeInfo(layoutName)
  ),
]);
```

`ChangeTransactionsInfoActions.UpdateChangeElementSequenceChange` is dependent on LayoutActions.SequenceChangeByDragDrop`enter code here` (*in this, we will update UI object which will be used in
`ChangeTransactionsInfoActions.UpdateChangeElementSequenceChange`*)

But as per the dispatched actions, I am expecting that the actions should be dispatched in the order maintained in the array but I see it not happening in my case.

I did not find any specific use case anywhere.

Comment: What dispatch order are you seeing ? (from log or Redux DevTools)

Comment: Hi, i did not check the logs or dev tools though. i have placed break-points in the state's class method and i have noticed this behaviour during the program execution.

Comment: They should be dispatched in the order you sent them. But, if they are asynchronous, they won't wait for each others. I suspect they are indeed dispatched in the right order, but SequenceChangeByDragDrop resolves after UpdateChangeElementSequenceChange is dispatched

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.
Upon further debugging , I noticed that the actions are indeed  dispatched in the right order specified but 
The method this.changeElementSequenceSectionChangeService.getChangeElementSequenceChangeInfo(layoutName)
Is called first and then the actions are executing in the order maintained .

Any clue here?

Comment: Oh, i didn't notice you were calling a function here. Maybe you need to rethink your UpdateChangeElementSequenceChange function so it get change element sequence change info by itself instead of passing it as an argument. When you pass an argument to a function, it will resolve before the function is executed. Hence, here, getChangeElementSequenceChangeInfo is called before the actions are even dispatched ;)